# hibernate - another auto generated field which is not the ID

Tags: hibernate

I want to create another autogenerated field in my class.
I followed this unanswered question - with no success

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930762/generate-an-auto-generated-value-of-a-field-under-java-hibernate-id-generatedv

I need even a more simple thing - 
I want my second field - to receive the same value as the @ID @AutoGenerated.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

As an example try like this.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "columnName", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer columnName;
```